# WPF WebBrowser fires button shortcut as ALT+Key is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a really strange problem with WPF.

A simple window with a button with a shortcut ("_Ok") and a webbrowser control.
The problem is: when the cursor is in a textarea inside the webbrowser when I press "o" wpf fires the button click as I'm pressing Alt+O

Here's the XAML for Windows1.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="testBrowser.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <WebBrowser Name="m_Browser" Focusable="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Margin="0"/>

    <TextBox Name="m_Text" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Button Name="m_Ok" Content="_Ok" Click="m_Ok_Click" Grid.Row="2" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind (just sets the browser content):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace testBrowser
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class Window1 : Window
  {
    public Window1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      m_Browser.NavigateToString("<textarea cols=\"20\" rows=\"10\"/>");
    }

    private void m_Ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Ok pressed");
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Fixed using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace testBrowser
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class Window1 : Window
  {
    public Window1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement), AccessKeyManager.AccessKeyPressedEvent, 
                                        new AccessKeyPressedEventHandler(OnAccessKeyPressed));

      m_Browser.NavigateToString("<textarea cols=\"20\" rows=\"10\"/>");
    }

    private void m_Ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Ok pressed");
    }

    private static void OnAccessKeyPressed(object sender, AccessKeyPressedEventArgs e)
    {    
      if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) != ModifierKeys.Alt) {
        e.Target = null;
        e.Handled = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following link: [AccessKey Pressed Event Raised when pressing access key without ALT](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/14f6f49f-0027-471b-b68c-e7f6ba012012) mnemonics work in WPF without the need to press the Alt key.

There is talk in the thread about this being changed in .net 4.0 however that is what I tested it with so It seems it has not been.

The thread describes a method that could work for you though.

Comment: Many thanks! It worked, I edit the question with the corrected code. ;)

Comment: @Paolo Iommarini No worries, glad to help.